# compare character based on ASCII precedence

Tags: c, character, scanf

I made a code that compare three character and sort it from highest to lowest precedence based on ASCII number. the first input is many cases to solve and then enter three character to sort. for example if we input `& ^ %` what we expect for the output is `Case #1: % & ^`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int cases, counter = 1;
    char ch1, ch2, ch3, storage;
    scanf("%d", &cases);
    getchar();

    while(counter <= cases){
        scanf("%c %c %c", &ch1, &ch2, &ch3);

        //process

        while(ch1 < ch2 < ch3){
            if(ch1 < ch2){
                storage = ch1;
                ch1 = ch2;
                ch2 = storage;
            }
            if(ch2 < ch3){
                storage = ch2;
                ch2 = ch3;
                ch3 = storage;
            }
        }

        //end process

        printf("case #%d: %c %c %c\n", counter, ch1, ch2, ch3);
        counter++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but it stuck after I entered the three character, it wont show the output and I cant enter any characters for the next case.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code.

Comment: Writing `while (ch1 < ch2 < ch3)` probably doesn't do what you think, especially if you learned Python first.  In C, it compares `ch1` with `ch2` and produces a value 0 or 1; then that value is compared with `ch3`.  Almost always, both 0 and 1 will be less than `ch3`, so the loop will continue, and continue, and continue, and continue, until you get bored with it.

Comment: Enable *compiler warnings* (e.g. minimum `-Wall -Wextra` for gcc/clang, and `/W3` for VS (`cl.exe`)) and do not accept code until it compiles without warning. Read and understand what your compiler is telling you.

Comment: " stuck after I entered the three character" --> Try `" %c %c %c"` instead of `"%c %c %c"`  (Add space).  Also `ch1 < ch2 < ch3` is a problem.

Comment: If by precedence you mean C operator precedence, then the assignment is nonsense. The unary address-of operator `&` has higher precedence than modulus `%` which in turn has higher precedence than bitwise AND `&`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh my god I didn't pay attention on my own thread for a year. Thank you for the explanation it is usefull. now I'm not sure whether I Solved the question to close the thread or let it open to answer. I was new to this site so I made an account for the sake of my school homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are stuck in your while loop, try reformatting the comparison.

```
while((ch1 < ch2) || (ch2 < ch3))
```